# What is the correct method to 301 redirect 500+ pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect 500+ pages. The original url references the product id, now they want it to reference the product name. For example:

from:
    `www.thedomain.com/bn/products/product-details/72`

to:
    `www.thedomain.com/bn/products/product-details/MR633`

I know the rewrite rule needs to be:

```
RewriteRule ^/bn/products/product-detail/72$ http://www.thedomain.com/bn/products/product-detail/MR633  [R=301]
```

Will I need to create all 500+ redirect lines manually to add to the htaccess file, or is there a different, better approach? Google has indexed all 500+ pages, so they don't want to lose that juice. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Also, is it OK/normal to have hundreds of redirects in an .htaccess file?